# How to make default codes to appear when you type a keyword and hit tab in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tabs, keyword

I started to learn Java in my computer science studies, and I need a lot to use printing methods `System.out.print();`, `System.out.println();`, and `System.out.printf();`, I searched in Google and I didn't find the right answer maybe cause I don't know how to ask it. Anyway, I'm looking for a way to  set up some ready codes to appear when I write a certain keyword and hit tab like in Sublime text in HTML we can just write "lorem" and press Tab and it will display the Lorem Ipsum paragraph.
Thank you for your help guys

Comment: Are you looking for "Code Recommenders" in eclipse?

Comment: I _think_ that you're looking for the feature called Snippets. As Vyom Yadav mentioned, there is a built-in snippet for `sysout` that completes to `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're called *Templates*, and are activated as part of content assist with Ctrl+Space. You'll find the page for them in your Preferences under Java->Editor->Templates.

Comment: Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

Write `sysout` and then press Ctrl + spacebar `System.out.println();` will be printed

Comment: Thank you bro that's so useful